# How can I open a workbook to fix it if it is popping up a runtime error?

Tags: excel, runtime-error

For some reason, a workbook of mine that has macros running is now popping up a run-time error saying `Method 'Visible' of object'_Worksheet' failed`. I have data that I need off of this workbook, but I cannot open it to even change my macros or open VBA at all. How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you change your security settings so it asks you to either enable o disable macros?  Do that using a blank/new workbook/empty Excel session, not the workbook that's causing you grief.

Comment: Clic on Debug and fix it when the error arises?